Is the function $(z-1)(2^{z}-1)\zeta(z)$ logarithmically concave and convex in $z\in(0,\infty)$?
For proving that the sequence
\begin{equation}\label{first-proof-decreas-seq}
\frac{1}{(2k-1)(k+1)} \frac{2^{2k+2}-1}{2^{2k}-1} \biggl|\frac{B_{2k+2}}{B_{2k}}\biggr|
\end{equation}
is decreasing in $k\in\mathbb{N}$, I need to show that the function $(z-1)(2^{z}-1)\zeta(z)$ is logarithmically concave in $z\in(0,\infty)$, where $B_k$ denotes the Bernoulli numbers and $\zeta(z)$ stands for the Riemann zeta function. Moreover, I believe that the function $(z-1)(2^{z}-1)\zeta(z)$ is convex in $z\in(0,\infty)$.
In a word, is the function $(z-1)(2^{z}-1)\zeta(z)$ logarithmically concave and convex in $z\in(0,\infty)$?

I got a proof for the logarithmic concavity of the function $(z-1)(2^z-1)\zeta(z)$ in $z\in(0,\infty)$, but the convexity is still open.
The sketch of my proof is as follows:

Rewrite the function $(z-1)(2^z-1)\zeta(z)$ as
$$
[2^{z-1}(2^{z}-1)]\frac{z-1}{2^{z-1}-1}\eta(z), \quad z>0,
$$
where $\eta(z)$ stands for the Dirichlet eta function.
Prove that the function $2^{z-1}(2^{z}-1)$ is logarithmically concave in $z\in(0,\infty)$. This is straightforward.
The Dirichlet eta function $\eta(z)$ is loagrithmically concave in $z\in(0,\infty)$. More strongly, the Dirichlet eta function $\eta(z)$ is concave in $z\in(0,\infty)$. The logarithmic concavity was known since 1998 and the concavity was known since 2015.
Prove that the function $\frac{z-1}{2^{z-1}-1}$ is logarithmically concave in $z\in(-\infty,\infty)$. This was known since 2011.
The product of finitely many logarithmically concave functions is still logarithmically concave on their common domain.

Consequently, the sequence
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(2k-1)(k+1)} \frac{2^{2k+2}-1}{2^{2k}-1} \biggl|\frac{B_{2k+2}}{B_{2k}}\biggr|
\end{equation}
is decreasing in $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
References

K. C. Wang, The logarithmic concavity of $(1-2^{1-r})\zeta(r)$, J. Changsha Comm. Univ. 14 (1998), no. 2, 1--5. (Chinese)
J. A. Adell and A. Lekuona, Dirichlet's eta and beta functions: concavity and fast computation of their derivatives, J. Number Theory 157 (2015), 215--222; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2015.05.006.
H. Alzer and M. K. Kwong, On the concavity of Dirichlet's eta function and related functional inequalities, J. Number Theory 151 (2015), 172--196; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2014.12.009.
B.-N. Guo and F. Qi, The function $(b^x-a^x)/x$: Logarithmic convexity and applications to extended mean values, Filomat 25 (2011), no. 4, 63--73; available online at http://dx.doi.org/10.2298/FIL1104063G.
Y. Shuang, B.-N. Guo, and F. Qi, Logarithmic convexity and increasing property of the Bernoulli numbers and their ratios, Rev. R. Acad. Cienc. Exactas Fis. Nat. Ser. A Mat. RACSAM 115 (2021), no. 3, Paper No. 135, 12 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s13398-021-01071-x.

